# Erro ao converter para vetor (->toArray()) no CakePHP

Tags: cakephp

Boa noite.

Estou criando uma função no arquivo `'src/Model/Table/ProdutosTable.php'`, utilizando a versão 3 do CakePHP.
A função deve retornar informações em um vetor de uma lista de produtos de acordo com a data selecionada. O problema é que
ao converter o resultado da 'Query' para um array, o mesmo passa a ficar vazio, não dando continuidade a lógica do código.
Alguém poderia me ajudar por favor?

Abaixo segue o código:

```
src/Model/Table/ProdutosTable.php

//Função para retornar uma lista de produtos.
public function lista($data = null) {
    //Variáveis
    $produtos_model = $this;
    $dados = [];
    $lista_produtos = [];

    //Formata a data.
    $data = new Time($data);
    $data = $data->format('Y-m-d');

    //Seleciona todos os produtos no banco de dados de acordo com os parâmetros passados.
    $query = produtos_model->find()
        ->where(['data' => $data]);

    //Converte o resultado para um array.
    $produtos = $query->toArray(); //Aqui ele deveria realizar a conversão, mas isto não acontece.//

    //Cria a lista com os dados necessarios.
    foreach($produtos as $produto) {
        $dados = [
            'id' => $produto->id,
            'nome' => $produto->nome,
            'referencia' = $produto->referencia
        ];

        array_push($lista_produtos, $dados);
    }

    //Retorna os dados.
    return $lista_produtos;
};
```

Comment: dê um `var_dump()` em `$query` e  `$produtos`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Em primeiro lugar gostaria de agradecer novamente ao @DanielOmine, que mais uma vez esta me ajudando aqui no Stack Overflow. E gostaria de pedir desculpas, pois sem querer eu postei o código já com a solução do problema. Isso mesmo, o código que encabeça este tópico já possuí a correção do bug. Novamente peço desculpas.
Quando eu escrevi o código aqui no Overflow eu não o copiei do meu ambiente de desenvolvimento e colei aqui (pois eu estava fora do mesmo). Na verdade eu reescrevi a função aqui, e quando o fiz, a reescrevi com a solução do problema, sem perceber.

O problema desta questão estava na variável '`$data`'. Esta variável é passada a partir de uma requisição ".json" para o controller "`ProdutosController.php`". Por uma questão de organização, estou colocando as funções que fazem acesso ao banco (Exceto as funções básicas do cake como a index(), add(), edit(), delete()...) no arquivo citado no início do post (`src/Model/Table/ProdutosTable.php`).

A questão era que no arquivo "`ProdutosController.php`" eu já convertia essa data para um objeto do tipo "Time" (`$data = new Time($data);`), mas não aplicava a função format (`->format('Y-m-d');`) na mesma. Então essa variável era passada para a função lista (`src/Model/Table/ProdutosTable.php`) com o seguinte conteúdo:

```
object(Cake\I18n\Time) {
    'time' => '2016-09-22T00:00:00+00:00',
    'timezone' => 'UTC',
    'fixedNowTime' => false
},
```

Quando deveria ser passada desta forma:

```
2016-09-22
```

Então, quando eu reescrevi a função aqui no Overflow com o trecho:

```
//Formata a data.
$data = new Time($data);
$data = $data->format('Y-m-d');
```

Isto já havia resolvido o problema ;)

Em fim, eu não sei explicar o porque a conversão para um vetor (`->toArray();`) não era realizada, mas ao realizar o format na variável `$data` o problema foi sanado.
Novamente peço desculpas pela falha. E muito obrigado a toda comunidade Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Se pretende obter um resultado aninhado em grupo,

Nesse trecho

```
    $query = produtos_model->find()
        ->where(['data' => $data]);

    //Converte o resultado para um array.
    $produtos = $query->toArray(); //Aqui ele deveria realizar a conversão, mas isto não acontece.//

    //Cria a lista com os dados necessarios.
    foreach($produtos as $produto) {
        $dados = [
            'id' => $produto->id,
            'nome' => $produto->nome,
            'referencia' = $produto->referencia
        ];

        array_push($lista_produtos, $dados);
    }
```

Modifique para

```
    $query = produtos_model->find('list',
        [
            'keyField' => 'nome',
            'valueField' => 'referencia',
            'groupField' => 'id',
        ]
    )
        ->where(['data' => $data]);

    //Converte o resultado para um array.
    $produtos = $query->toArray();
```

Mas não está claro qual a finalidade de uso, pois há opções diversas para cada propósito.

Talvez ao invés de `list`, você queira usar `threaded`.

Consulte os exemplos do manual
http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#finding-key-value-pairs

Comment: Bom dia @DanielOmine.

O problema é que se eu comento esta linha "//$produtos = $query->toArray();" e retornar a variável $query, ele retorna os objetos da minha requisição em find(). Mas se eu voltar a tirar o comentário, a variável produtos é retornada vazia ([ ]).

Obs.: Estou utilizando o método 'debug()' do CakePHP 3 para verificar o estado interno de retorno da função.